# iBeacon monitoring implementation ios7.1

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I’ve a problem about iBeacon monitoring implementation. I fire a local notification when locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion: method is called. When application goes in background I don’t get any local notification at all but they came all at once when I active the screen pushing the home button. According to time I leave sleep the device I can get up to tens notification always when I wake it up. How is that possible? Anyone had the same problem?

I use iPhone 5S and 5C with iOS 7.1. The local notification is set in this way:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

    UILocalNotification *localNot = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNot.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Region state %d determined", state];
    localNot.alertAction = @"Go for it!";
    localNot.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNot.fireDate = nil;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNot];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are not actually doing any background detections at all, and the reason you see the notifications when you hit the home button is because you have the `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay` flag set, which causes you to get an extra callback to `didDetermineState: forRegion:` whenever the screen comes on, for every region you are monitoring with the flag set.

Why do you not get callbacks in the background?  You may need to wait up to 15 minutes to detect an iBeacon in the background, even on iOS 7.1.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html).

Comment: How can I check if I’m doing background monitoring? I enabled both notifications and Location services in Settings. I start the monitoring and ranging with following code:
_beaconManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:REGION_UUID] major:MAJOR identifier:REGION_ID];
_beaconManager.delegate = self;
 _beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
    [_beaconManager startMonitoringForRegion:_beaconRegion];
 [_beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:_beaconRegion];

Comment: Background monitoring is automatic. You do not need to do anything special.  Simply hit the home button and keep your screen on during testing, then be extra patient as you wait up too 15 min to get a background detection.  Keeping the screen on avoids the extra notifications you get from _beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;  alternately, you can change that to NO for testing.